# How to move ANDROID_SDK_HOME

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

I visited a question which the verified answer said 
"Setting ANDROID_SDK_HOME to a newly created empty directory, then creating a new AVD device has helped." (@AlexanderKulyakhtin). Where can one find ANDROID_SDK_HOME and how do I move it to an empty directory?

If you are curious, this is a proposed solution to the error:

```
[123145305600000]:WARNING:./android/base/files/IniFile.cpp:158:Failed 
to process .ini file /Users/Ryan/.android/emu-update-last-check.ini for reading.

[123145311502336]:WARNING:./android/base/files/IniFile.cpp:158:Failed 
to process .ini file /Users/Ryan/.android/emu-update-last-check.ini for reading.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` referred is just an environment variable that points to the sdk home directory. So the solution wants you to move that directory and update the environment variable.

Comment: I understand that part, but how do I move that directory?

Comment: @Ryan Cocuzzo Are you using Mac? Open finder, go to where SDK is located, move it somewhere else, then update the environment variable.